# Is there any way we can compare the data types of two numbers?

Tags: java, types, double

I'm from Mechanical background and started coding in java recently. I'm looking for a solution for the below question. Here's my work in brief :

1. Input 2 double values from the user(using scanner).
2. Check data type.
3. If arguments are not doubles, supply suitable error message & terminate

I need to know on how to use 'hasNextDouble' for checking the data type in above 'step 2'

Comment: Please show your code. Are you even calling `hasNextDouble`?

Comment: User input is not an argument. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this :

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(" 22.10 2123324.58 S ");
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            if(scan.hasNextDouble()){
                System.out.println("Found Double Value: "+scan.next());
            }
            else{
                throw new IllegalStateException("This is not a double value: "+scan.next());
            }
        }
        scan.close();
```